# Configure router and switch to share internet over network

Tags: networking, ip, adsl, wired-networking

We have one TP-Link ADSL (Modem/Router) and one D-Link 5-port switch connected via a CAT5 cable. The TP-Link has configured ADSL internet connection and is working. We also have 4 client pc (all Windows 7 OS) that connect to one workgroup via the D-Link switch in a star network structure:

[image: SU538938 example]

How do I configure clients and switch (IP and other settings) so that internet is shared by the network and all four clients can connect?

Comment: Would be important to know whether your modem has a built in router (i.e. whether its able to establish the connection on its own or whether a computer in the network has to do it).

Comment: yes, the modem has a built in router and the internet access on modem is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to worry about any further configuration. Let all clients determine their IP by DHCP (the router should answer them and assign them a dynamic IP).

If this doesn't work, either ensure the DHCP server of the modem/router is active or assign them manual IPs being in the same network as the modem/router. Usually it's enough to use the modem/router's IP and change the last octet (e.g. from `.1` to `.2`). Also make sure you're using the same network mask. Also set the modem/router's IP to be your "Default Gateway" as well as the "Primary DNS". Once this is done, all internet access should work and clients should be able to talk to each other as well.

Comment: I need that clients has static ip, so I set the 192.168.0.xxx ip on client and DHCP on swith is off, Switch IP is 192.168.0.1 and Modem/router IP is 192.168.1.1 but client has no internet.

Comment: Have you set your default gateway and DNS server? Both should be your modem/router's IP.

Comment: yes I set Gateway and DNS to 192.168.1.1 it's modem IP's

Comment: And still doesn't work? Are you able to ping others in network and/or the router by name and/or IP?

Comment: yes, I can ping these

Comment: But not by names? Or what's the specific issue you're still facing?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7182/discussion-between-poorhoseini-and-mario)